# Blank Labels for tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Good morning,

I am trying to create blank line segments or boxes for both legs and also the hypotenuse so students to fill in the blank so to speak. I tried creating my own command but it does not seem to work.   Similar to attached picture, but remove the letters and replace with a box or line for a,b, and c.  [image]Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\newcommand{\nick}[2][{}]{%
\fillin[#1][0.5in]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0,3){A}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle(A,C,B){\footnotesize{$45^\circ$}}
\tkzLabelAngle(B,A,C){\footnotesize{$45^\circ$}}
\tkzLabelSegment[below](B,C){\nick}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Similar to attached picture, but remove the letters and replace with a box or line for a,b, and c." >>> can you give a hand drawing of exactly what you want to obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this

```
\tkzLabelSegment[below](B,C){\framebox(20,20){}}
```

and it works.  Let me know if you have another solution!

Comment: Why would you look for another solution? This one is absolutely fine! And, not related, but you should add `\tkzMarkAngle[size=.6](A,C,B)` and `\tkzMarkAngle[size=.6](B,A,C)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is for fun with only 1 TikZ command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] 
(0,0) rectangle +(-.3,.3) 
(0,0)  coordinate (C) node[below right]{$C$}--      
(0,3)  coordinate (B) node[above right]{$B$} node[midway,right]{$a$}--
(-4,0) coordinate (A) node[below left]{$A$}  node[midway,sloped,above]{$c$}--
cycle node[midway,below]{$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```